# How to restart an Xcode project in Bitbucket

Tags: git, project, xcode, bitbucket

I currently have an Xcode project which has a remote in the organizer for a Bithucket repository. I want to start the project over with a fresh template. However I do not want to lose all my previous commits I just want a brand new project in Xcode but to Bitbucket it should just be like another commit. How do I go about in doing this? I would like instructions on what I do in Xcode and what I do in Bitbucket. Thanks in advance!